# How to import data from file lets say .csv to djagno model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to export data from django models from django admin panel, how can i quickly make it happen, i am new to django so don't have much idea, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this task is fairly easy in django admin, there are two options

First option -
You can use django-import-export library

https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/

Second option-

you can override django admin page, follow link below

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/export.html